# Issue on Ajax request (Liferay)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, liferay

I'm trying to pass this simple input on every keypress, to an ajax handler, and then to a controller:

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL">
</portlet:resourceURL>

   <form id="busq" method="POST">
   <input id="busqueda" name="param1" type="text" onkeypress="buscar()"/>
   </form>
```

This is my ajax call. It seems to work ok: it sends the parameter in the POST request, and retrieves some data back from the server:

```
var busq = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;
    console.log("Searching for: "+busq);
    AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){
        A.io.request('${resourceURL}', {
               method: 'post',
               data: {
                   parametro: busq
               },
               on: {
                    success: function() {
                    console.log("RESULT: "+this.get('responseData'));
                   },
                   error: function(){
                       alert("Error");
                   }
              }
        });

    });
```

This is how I read it in the controller. It currently retrieves an empty string:

```
String datos = ParamUtil.get(req, "param2", StringPool.BLANK);
```

I tried all the following:

- Using namespaces
- Setting  to false (current status).
- Changing variable names.
- Using ParamUtil.getString().
- etc...

Nothing worked. I want to get the input value in my controller, so I can filter a search, but it never gets there (so I get all the query info without any filtering).

Any idea on what's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the parameter name you are sending is parametro. You can inspect the request in your controller and see what the parameters are, that might help

Comment: It would be good if you provide code for what all options you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are usig wrong parameter name while getting value :
   String datos = ParamUtil.get(req, "param2", StringPool.BLANK);

Try this code in your controller :
    String datos = ParamUtil.get(req, "parametro", StringPool.BLANK);